# A Bunch of questions regarding Android PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

I'm using `PreferenceActivity` to set some preferences about another `BroadcastReciever` that i have.

While making the skeleton of the preferences GUI is really simple with XML file, i cant find my hands and legs around how to actually DO something with those preferences. especially:

1. How do i register my `BroadcastReciever` to listen to changes in my preferences?
   Its look like that the context of the broadcast reciever is not the same as the activity so i'm not registering to the right `SharedPreferences` because i dont intercept those changes.
2. How do i act in my `PreferenceActivity` upon changes in the preferences? i guess i dont need to register `PreferenceActivity` as listener to the preferences, so there must be more simple way.
3. How do i change the UI of the `PreferenceActivity` appropriate to the changes in the preferences? for example, set the "Summary" attribute of a preference to the value that the user chose?
4. How do i enable or disable some preferences that depends on another preference (like `CheckBoxPreference`)? so the user could edit those preferences only if he enabled the feature first.

I looked al over the documentation but there is no example of using `PreferenceActivity` beyond the point of just adding preferences from XML.

I feel like i'm missing something huge here, because it looks so simple, and yet i can't figure it out...

Please try to answer on any of my question.

BTW:
I'm developing for Android 1.6 so all the new `PreferenceFragment` can't be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do i register my BroadcastReciever to listen to changes in my preferences?

If the `BroadcastReceiver` is registered in the manifest, you don't listen to changes in your preferences, because the `BroadcastReceiver` will only be around for milliseconds. Just read the latest values in during `onReceive()`.

If the `BroadcastReceiver` is registered by some other component calling `registerReceiver()`, that component can register an `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` with the `SharedPreferences` retrieved via `PreferenceManager` and `getDefaultSharedPreferences()`.

> Its look like that the context of the broadcast reciever is not the same as the activity so i'm not registering to the right SharedPreferences because i dont intercept those changes.

That sentence makes no sense.

> How do i act in my PreferenceActivity upon changes in the preferences?

Register an `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` with the `SharedPreferences` retrieved via `PreferenceManager` and `getDefaultSharedPreferences()`.

> How do i change the UI of the PreferenceActivity appropriate to the changes in the preferences?

Generally, you don't. You are welcome to register an `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` with the `SharedPreferences` retrieved via `PreferenceManager` and `getDefaultSharedPreferences()`. From there, you can get the `Preference` from your `PreferenceActivity` via `findPreference()` and adjust to suit.

> How do i enable or disable some preferences that depends on another preference (like CheckBoxPreference)? so the user could edit those preferences only if he enabled the feature first.

Add `android:dependency` to your preference XML as needed.

Comment: I saw that android:dependency but i didnt new what value should i provide. can you elaborate on that a little?

Comment: @Avrahamshuk: As the documentation says, it is "the key of another Preference that this Preference will depend on". If you have a preference named "foo" and one named "bar", and "bar" should only be enabled if "foo" is checked, then add `android:dependency="foo"` to the "bar" preference in the XML.

Comment: Use the "key" value of CheckBox. <CheckBoxPreference android:key="preference_send_data" ... /> <EditTextPreference android:dependency="preference_send_data" ... />